# Print output of code in the middle of the screen

Tags: command-line, scripts

The code below will output whatever in `file` word by word on the screen. For example:

`Hello`  will be displayed for 1 second and disappear. Then, the next word in the sentence will appear for a second and disappear and so on.

How do I output whatever is being displayed in the middle of the screen?

```
awk '{i=1; while(i<=NF){ print $((i++)); system("sleep 1; clear") }}' file
```

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve, exactly?

Comment: that command displays each word form a file in the top left corner of the screen. I need to know how to make the output in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Yes, but what are you trying to achieve? This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem),

Comment: What's the "middle of a screen"? The middle of a terminal? The middle of the actual screen? What if you resize the terminal, do you need this to dynamically place the text in the middle whatever size your terminal has?

Comment: yes. The middle of terminal.

Comment: OK, you have tagged with bash but are using awk, not bash. Does that mean you are open to solutions using any tool?

Comment: yea I'm open to solutions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you're a very robust bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## When the program is interrupted, call the cleanup function
trap "cleanup; exit" SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM

## Check if file exists
[ -f "$1" ] || { echo "File not found!"; exit; }

function cleanup() {
    ## Restores the screen content
    tput rmcup

    ## Makes the cursor visible again
    tput cvvis
}

## Saves the screen contents
tput smcup

## Loop over all words
while read line
do
    ## Gets terminal width and height
    height=$(tput lines)
    width=$(tput cols)

    ## Gets the length of the current word
    line_length=${#line}

    ## Clears the screen
    clear

    ## Puts the cursor on the middle of the terminal (a bit more to the left, to center the word)
    tput cup "$((height/2))" "$((($width-$line_length)/2))"

    ## Hides the cursor
    tput civis

    ## Prints the word
    printf "$line"

    ## Sleeps one second
    sleep 1

## Passes the words separated by a newline to the loop
done < <(tr ' ' '\n' < "$1")

## When the program ends, call the cleanup function
cleanup
```

Answer (score 9):

Try the script below. It will detect the size of the terminal for every input word so will even dynamically update if you resize the terminal while it's running.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Change the input file to have one word per line
tr ' ' '\n' < "$1" | 
## Read each word
while read word
do
    ## Get the terminal's dimensions
    height=$(tput lines)
    width=$(tput cols)
    ## Clear the terminal
    clear

    ## Set the cursor to the middle of the terminal
    tput cup "$((height/2))" "$((width/2))"

    ## Print the word. I add a newline just to avoid the blinking cursor
    printf "%s\n" "$word"
    sleep 1
done
```

Save it as `~/bin/foo.sh`, make it executable (`chmod a+x ~/bin/foo.sh`) and give it your input file as its first argument:

```
foo.sh file
```

Answer (score 3):

bash function to do the same

```bsh
mpt() { 
   clear ; 
   w=$(( `tput cols ` / 2 ));  
   h=$(( `tput lines` / 2 )); 
   tput cup $h;
   printf "%${w}s \n"  "$1"; tput cup $h;
   sleep 1;
   clear;  
}
```

and then

```
mpt "Text to show"
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly the same as my answer except that it shows one thing and not every word of a sentence read from a file separately as requested by the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's Python script that is similar to [@Helio's `bash` solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/599660/3712):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import fileinput
import signal
import sys
import time
from blessings import Terminal # $ pip install blessings

def signal_handler(*args):
    raise SystemExit

for signal_name in "SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM".split():
    signal.signal(getattr(signal, signal_name), signal_handler)

term = Terminal()
with term.hidden_cursor(), term.fullscreen():
    for line in fileinput.input(): # read from files on the command-line and/or stdin
        for word in line.split(): # whitespace-separated words
            # use up to date width/height (SIGWINCH support)
            with term.location((term.width - len(word)) // 2, term.height // 2):
                print(term.bold_white_on_black(word))
                time.sleep(1)
                print(term.clear)
```